# Cross Browser Fill Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

What's the best way to fill out a navigation cross browser. It seems like every browser has it's different definition of `Padding` so when it comes to Navigation, how to websites fill out the navigation completely, especially when it comes to navigation animations?

For example, if I have a container holding my navigation set at `1000px` - how can I dynamically fill that 1000px while providing space between my list items effectively? I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nFxn/) to express my problem. [Found Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4nFxn/).

My code looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li class="first"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Something</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

and css like this:

```
*                       {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
#container              {margin: 0 auto; width: 1000px; background-color: #eee;}
#container ul           {position: relative;}
#container li           {float: left; list-style: none;}
#container li a         {display: block; padding: 10px 44px; color: #000; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-right: 1px solid #000; text-decoration: none;}
#container li.first a   {border-left: 0;}
#container li.last a    {border-right: 0;}
```

So I'm currently using padding, which looks different from Chrome to Firefox or Firefox to IE so how do I make it universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `dispaly:table-cell'` for the buttons in the navigation menu.
then just set `table-layout:fixed;`.

Here is a quick example: [**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/Lcbrq/)

```
#container {

    width:800px;
}
#container ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
#container ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**Browser Compatibility:**

Its widely supported (I think its enough) take a look: [caniuse.com/css-table](http://caniuse.com/css-table)

**Important Notes**

1. That's (css display table rules) are CSS2 - Widely supported.
2. The `table-layout` property sets the table layout algorithm to be used for a table.
3. you can set rows too by setting display too: `display:table-row` and many more:

   Available CSS2 Table Model:

   - table    { display: table }
   - tr       { display: table-row }
   - thead    { display: table-header-group }
   - tbody    { display: table-row-group }
   - tfoot    { display: table-footer-group }
   - col      { display: table-column }
   - colgroup { display: table-column-group }
   - td, th   { display: table-cell }
   - caption  { display: table-caption }
4. More information: [W3C - The CSS table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display)

Comment: That works, but the JS I have is adding another list item which is throwing it off. Kudos if you can find a solution to it, but since that wasn't part of the question - i like this answer best Thanks!

Comment: Need more information on the JS issue and the UL structure after the JS kicks in...

Comment: Right it's adding in the list item on dom ready - which css then counts it as a `table-cell`. I think the only way to get around it is to either increase the UL width to overflow 100%, then hide overflow on the container or modify the JS to not use List Items. Either way it's probably a different questions entirely, thanks for you response though!